# How would I select the first word only on this string

Tags: php, select, filter

I have a bit of code that is currently working and returning a location variable.
How do I make it so it only takes the first word of a variable?
Currently it is returning for example "Inverness, Highland"
I want it to return "Inverness" Only.

```
<?php 
echo apply_filters( 
    "adverts_tpl_single_location", 
    esc_html( get_post_meta( $post_id, "adverts_location", true ) ), 
    $post_id ) 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$all_locations = apply_filters( 
    "adverts_tpl_single_location", 
    esc_html( get_post_meta( $post_id, "adverts_location", true ) ), 
    $post_id );
$locations = explode(',', $all_locations); // since the list is comma separated
echo $locations[0]; // should be 'Inverness'
```

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: This will only work when the delimiter is a comma though.

Comment: True @ErikKalkoken, but that is all the OP gave us to work with. My crystal ball is in the shop. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to select the first alphanumeric characters of a string.

For example:

```
$firstword = preg_replace('/^([\d\w]+).*?$/', '$1', 'Inverness, Highland');
```

You can see the regular expression in action here: http://regexr.com/3fe20

Comment: Hey Jero - Thanks for the response not sure how I'd implement that with the code I've posted,  My knowledge goes as far as cut and paste trial and error ! ha

Comment: Be aware that \d is redundant (covered by \w already, so the class is not necessary), and \w can cause problems with umlauts etc.. See https://eval.in/744710 for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to get only the first word of a string. Note that I included a space and a comma as possible delimiters.

```
$firstWord = strtok('Inverness, Highland', ' ,');
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you went and reverted back to German on this http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42513691/3 where I edited to use an English-based reference http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42513691/2 and Jay Blanchard's also http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42513691/4

Comment: It was a misunderstanding. I changed it to English reference again.